# iPhone app on iPad - start with 2X instead 1X

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

is it possible to ask an iPad running my iPhone app to automatically run with 2X zoom instead of launching with 1X and forcing the user to click the 2X button every time?

Comment: Unfortunately. It’s not possible, because it’s an iPhone app

Comment: No. But why doesn’t your app support iPad directly so you won’t have this issue?

Comment: it should... but will take some development and QA...
wanted to see if we can have a solution in the meanwhile